# Cypher query fails with variable length paths when trying to find all paths with unique node occurences

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a highly interconnected graph where starting from a specific node
i want to find all nodes connected to it regardless of the relation type, direction or length. What i am trying to do is to filter out paths that include a node more than 1 times. But what i get is a

```
Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError: key not found: UNNAMED27
```

I have managed to create a much simpler database 
in neo4j sandbox and get the same message again using the following data:

```
CREATE (n1:Person { pid:1, name: 'User1'}), 
       (n2:Person { pid:2, name: 'User2'}),
       (n3:Person { pid:3, name: 'User3'}), 
       (n4:Person { pid:4, name: 'User4'}),
       (n5:Person { pid:5, name: 'User5'})
```

With the following relationships:

```
MATCH (n1{pid:1}),(n2{pid:2}),(n3{pid:3}),(n4{pid:4}),(n5{pid:5})
CREATE (n1)-[r1:RELATION]->(n2), 
       (n5)-[r2:RELATION]->(n2), 
       (n1)-[r3:RELATION]->(n3), 
       (n4)-[r4:RELATION]->(n3)
```

The Cypher Query that causes this issue in the above model is

```
MATCH p= (n:Person{pid:1})-[*0..]-(m) 
WHERE ALL(c IN nodes(p) WHERE 1=size(filter(d in nodes(p) where c.pid = d.pid)) ) 
return  m
```

Can anybody see what is wrong with this query?

Comment: Tested 3.2.6 and it this error still occurs

Answer (score 3):

The error seems like a bug to me. There is a [closed neo4j issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/9436) that seems similar, but it was supposed to be fixed in version 3.2.1. You should probably create a new issue for it, since your comments state you are using 3.2.5.

Meanwhile, this query should get the results you seem to want:

```
MATCH p=(:Person{pid:1})-[*0..]-(m)
WITH m, NODES(p) AS ns
UNWIND ns AS n
WITH m, ns, COUNT(DISTINCT n) AS cns
WHERE SIZE(ns) = cns
return m
```

You should strongly consider putting a reasonable upper bound on your variable-length path search, though. If you do not do so, then with any reasonable DB size your query is likely to take a *very* long time and/or run out of memory.

Comment: Thank you very much for your excellent reply. Unfortunately this query never ends when i try it in my actual database. And probably this is because it falls in cycles which is what i wanted to avoid with the where clause in my little example. The query you provided does not avoid cycles either but works well in this small dataset. Your are right it seems like  the older neo4j issue and probably i will ask for it once i find some time.

Answer (score 0):

When finding paths, Cypher will never visit the same node twice in a single path. So `MATCH (a:Start)-[*]-(b) RETURN DISTINCT b` will return all nodes connected to a. (DISTINCT here is redundant, but it can affect query performance. Use PROFILE on your version of Neo4j to see if it cares and which is better)

NOTE: This works starting with Neo4j 3.2 Cypher planner. For previous versions of 
 the Cypher planner, the only performant way to do this is with APOC, or add a `-[:connected_to]->` relation from start node to all children so that path doesn't have to be explored.)

Comment: In my larger Database i have tried removing this WHERE clause. Resulted in a never ending query. I limited the results (to eventually get an answer) and saw that it actually visited some nodes twice thus falling into cycles. Also Profile does not work because it actually tries to perform the query. Explain only resulted in seeing that this UNNAMED27 probably refers to the unnamed var length relationship which i can no longer give a name to.

Comment: @iltzortz What version of Neo4j are you using? Also, you can limit the depth with `()-[*..5]-()`.

Comment: @iltzortz The WHERE clause doesn't actually help the time of the MATCH it's for. The filter is applied after an initial filter-less quick search fails, and with a deeply connected graph, that initial scan can lock up the query.

Comment: version 3.2.5 I know i can set an upper limit i just do not want to.

Comment: @iltzortz Are you using DISTINCT? var-length match with distinct will tell the 3.2.* Cypher planner to use a more efficient pruning type search. And how many results are you returning? (You should be paging your results if there are alot)

Comment: @Tezra: A `MATCH` clause can return the same *node* multiple times, but it will not produce paths with the same *relationship* twice.